# Durandal knockout array undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, durandal

I have a problem to remove objects from the knockout array. What do I wrong? It says: TypeError: that.active_periods is undefined. So what is wrong at: that.active_periods.removeAll(freeDay);

periods.js

```
define(function (require) {
        var backend = require('backend');
        var ko = require('knockout');
        var app = require('durandal/app');

        return {
            active_periods:ko.observableArray([]),
            activate:function(){
                var that = this;
                backend.getActivePeriods().then(function(results){
                    that.active_periods(results);
                });
            },
            editActivePeriod:function(period){
                period.viewUrl = 'views/editActivePeriod';
                app.showDialog(period);
            },
            editFreeDays:function(){
                alert("hh");
            },
            deleteFreeDays:function(freeDay){
                var that = this;
                app.showMessage('Willst du wirklich diese freien Tag(e) löschen?', '', [ { text: "Ja", value: "Yes" }, { text: "Nein", value: "No" }],true, { style:  { width: "600px", height: "600" } }).then(function(response){
                if(response == "Yes"){
                    that.active_periods.removeAll(freeDay);
                }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

periods.html

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3 class="center-block">aktive Perioden</h3>
            <hr>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> neue Periode erstellen</button>
            <br>
            <!-- ko foreach: active_periods -->
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        <!--ko text: name--><!--/ko--> (<!--ko text: startDate--><!--/ko--> - <!--ko text: endDate--><!--/ko-->)<i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg pull-right" data-bind="click:$parent.editActivePeriod"></i>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul data-bind="foreach: freeDays">
                        <li>
                            <!--ko text: name--><!--/ko-->
                            <i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-lg pull-right" data-bind="click:$parents[1].deleteFreeDays"></i>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>archivierte Perioden</h3>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, an object literal that's being constructed cannot yet refer to itself. #`active_periods` is defined on the very literal you're referencing.

Change your code to this:

```
define(function (require) {
    var backend = require('backend');
    var ko = require('knockout');
    var app = require('durandal/app');

    var active_periods = ko.observableArray([]);  //<-Declared outside the reveal

    return {
        active_periods: active_periods, //<-Referenced here
        activate:function(){
            var that = this;
            backend.getActivePeriods().then(function(results){
                that.active_periods(results);
            });
        },
        editActivePeriod:function(period){
            period.viewUrl = 'views/editActivePeriod';
            app.showDialog(period);
        },
        editFreeDays:function(){
            alert("hh");
        },
        deleteFreeDays:function(freeDay){
            var that = this;
            app.showMessage('Willst du wirklich diese freien Tag(e) löschen?', '', [ { text: "Ja", value: "Yes" }, { text: "Nein", value: "No" }],true, { style:  { width: "600px", height: "600" } }).then(function(response){
                if(response == "Yes"){
                    that.active_periods.removeAll(freeDay);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**AN EVEN BETTER WAY**

**Let's go one step further**, and use the *Revealing Module Pattern*.  If you're not familiar with this pattern, please let me know.  Also, I do hope you're aware that you're using a singleton pattern here.  With that said, consider this:

```
define(function (require) {
    var    
        backend = require('backend'),
        ko = require('knockout'),
        app = require('durandal/app'),

        active_periods = ko.observableArray([]),

        activate = function() {
            backend.getActivePeriods().then(function(results){
                active_periods(results);
            });
        },

        editActivePeriod = function(period){
            period.viewUrl = 'views/editActivePeriod';
            app.showDialog(period);
        },

        editFreeDays = function(){
            alert("hh");
        },

        deleteFreeDays = function(freeDay){
            app.showMessage('Willst du wirklich diese freien Tag(e) löschen?', '', [ { text: "Ja", value: "Yes" }, { text: "Nein", value: "No" }],true, { style:  { width: "600px", height: "600" } }).then(function(response){
                if(response == "Yes"){
                    active_periods.removeAll(freeDay);
                }
            });
        };

    return {
        active_periods: active_periods,
        activate: activate,
        editActivePeriod: editActivePeriod,
        editFreeDays: editFreeDays,
        deleteFreeDays: deleteFreeDays
    };        
});
```

I hope that helps.

**UPDATE: Enhanced deleteFreeDays**

After adding a reference to the **UnderscoreJS** library, we make a few other modifications.

```
define(function (require) {
    var    
        backend = require('backend'),
        ko = require('knockout'),
        _ = require('underscore'),    //<--Add a reference to UnderscoreJS (or LodashJS)
        app = require('durandal/app'),

        active_periods = ko.observableArray([]),

        activate = function() {
            backend.getActivePeriods().then(function(results){
                active_periods(results);
            });
        },

        editActivePeriod = function(period){
            period.viewUrl = 'views/editActivePeriod';
            app.showDialog(period);
        },

        editFreeDays = function(){
            alert("hh");
        },

        //Return an array where no element of the array equals freeDay
        _removeAllFreeDays = function (freeDay) {             //<--Private function: not exported
            return _.reject(active_periods, function (day) {
                return _.isEqual(day, freeDay);
            });
        }

        deleteFreeDays = function(freeDay){
            app.showMessage('Willst du wirklich diese freien Tag(e) löschen?', '', [ { text: "Ja", value: "Yes" }, { text: "Nein", value: "No" }],true, { style:  { width: "600px", height: "600" } }).then(function(response){
                if(response == "Yes"){
                    active_periods.removeAll();            //<--Empty observableArray
                    active_periods(_removeAllFreeDays(freeDay));  //<--Fill observableArray with new array devoid of freeDays                       
                }
            });
        };

    return {
        active_periods: active_periods,
        activate: activate,
        editActivePeriod: editActivePeriod,
        editFreeDays: editFreeDays,
        deleteFreeDays: deleteFreeDays
    };        
});
```

Comment: While an object literal can not directly refer to itself, functions defined on an object literal *can* refer to the object literal itself, if it's assigned to a variable.  So instead of either solution here, they could also simply assign the object literal to a variable and return that, rather than returning the literal direction.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I get one both solution again the same error. But where is now the error?

Comment: @fibi I apologize, but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @Dziamid Got it.  Thank you.  I was trying to preserve his original intent.  So I didn't go too far in revising his code.

Comment: Thank you really much, no it works! But I have still on problem, I want to remove this object but it doesn't work, what do I wrong?

Comment: @fibi Excellent. Be sure to mark the answer as the correct one so we know that it worked.  As for "remov[ing] this object," to what object are you referring?

Comment: @fibi Sorry, I see what you mean.  What is the type of freeDay?

Comment: @EricTaylor  freeDay is an array. It looks like this in JSON: `{"name":"Weihachten","startDate":"20.12.2014","endDate":"22.12.2014"}`. Is it maybe a problem that the varnames are the same as in the array active_periods?

Comment: @fibi `removeAll` doesn't do a deep comparison when determining equality. `removeAll` can handle simple comparisons, such as comparing two strings, numbers, etc., but it would otherwise have no idea how to compare two `freeDay`s.  I use a mark-and-sweep approach in these cases, iterating over the array and replacing each item that meets certain criteria with a marker.  Then, I reject those items that are equal to the marker.  UnderscoreJS and LodashJS are great libraries for this kind of work.  It gets even more complicated if some of the object's properties are, themselves, observable.

Comment: @fibi Take a look at my update.  I show you one possible way to achieve your goal with `deleteFreeDays`, and without using mark-and-sweep. Again, this assumes that properties of the `freeDay` object are not, themselves, observable.  Even then there is an easy solution.

Comment: @EricTaylor shouldn't it be `activePeriods(_removeAllFreeDays(freeDay));` and not `activePeriods(_removeAllFreeDays());`

Comment: @EricTaylor I don't know really if `freeDay` is observable, but I think not. Is is only a copy of an object from `freeDays` with is an sub item of `active_periods`, isn't it? And would editing this values from active_periods even hard as deleting them?

Comment: @fibi It's not whether `freeDay` is observable, but whether any of its *properties* are.  If `freeDay` itself were observable, we would simply need to dereference it with `freeDay()`.  And, no, deleting selectively is generally tougher than editing, IMO.  Could you post your `freeDay` class (object, definition, etc.)?

Comment: @EricTaylor `freeDay` is not a class, but the parent object which is passed by `data-bind="click:$root.deleteFreeDays"`.

Comment: @fibi O.K. In any case, we're not advancing this conversation.  Did you implement the changes I recommended in my update?